# PHP push_array overwrites data

Tags: php, array-push

Sorry to ask if it was already asked before, but none of those solutions worked for me. Everytime I try to add into array, what I get is new array.
See PHP code below:

```
<?php    
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['$rNumber'])){
    $_SESSION['$rNumber'] = 0;
}

if(empty($_SESSION['words']))
{
    $_SESSION['words'] = array();
}

if (isset($_POST['button1'])){
    $random = rand(10, 20);
    $_SESSION['$rNumber'] = $_SESSION['$rNumber'] + $random;
    $word  = 'You entered a farm and earned '.$random.' golds.';
    array_push($_SESSION['words'], $word);
} else if ...

}
?>
```

When I var_dump the $words[], it always has 1 value only, though I add this very many times!
Please let me know if additional info needed.
Thanks!

Comment: note that `'$rNumber'` is going to put an entry in your array where the key is the literal characters `$`, `r`, `N`, etc...

Comment: @JayBlanchard: what good would that do? `[]` is the push operator, and as written you'd be pushing nothing because it has to be `$arr[] = $something`.

Comment: I am curious why you expect `$_SESSION['words'][]` to have more than one entry? No loop, so I am guessing you want it to add a new element to the array each time something is Posted?

Comment: Why not: `$_SESSION['$rNumber'] += $random;` - not addressing your issue, but makes life a bit nicer.

Comment: I think you are trying to generate a random number every time the button is clicked and store those random numbers in array. If I am right, what are you doing with sessions here? Are you submitting the form?

Comment: @SamSB Im just wandering who had the right answer for your question? Can you please check the answer as right - i mean the one that helped you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inspecting the wrong variable with var_dump() So try to `var_dump($_SESSION['words'])` and not `var_dump($words)`. I tried it and it works for me. Array push adds the value `$word` into `$_SESSION['words']`, therefore you have to var_dump the `$_SESSION['words']` because `$word` is still just a string, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it like this:

`$_SESSION['words'][] = 'You entered a farm and earned '.$random.' golds.';`

instead of:
`$word  = 'You entered a farm and earned '.$random.' golds.';
array_push($_SESSION['words'], $word);`

**UPDATE:**
From php.net: Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your suggestions. I made these changes and it worked!

```
<?php

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['$rNumber'])){
    $_SESSION['$rNumber'] = 0;
}

if(empty($_SESSION['words']))
{
    $_SESSION['words'] = array();
}


if (isset($_POST['button1'])){
    $random = rand(10, 20);
    $_SESSION['$rNumber'] = $_SESSION['$rNumber'] + $random;
    $word  = 'You entered a farm and earned '.$random.' golds.';
    array_push($_SESSION['words'], $word);
} else if...
```

Answer (score -1):

A few issues, as @MarcB pointed out, you should have a set Index name for your SESSION variable.

```
<?php    
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['gold'])){
    $_SESSION['gold'] = 0;
}

if(empty($_SESSION['words']))
{
    $_SESSION['words'] = array();
}

if (isset($_POST['button1'])){
    $random = rand(10, 20);
    $_SESSION['gold'] += $random;
    $word = "You entered a farm and earned $random golds.";
    $_SESSION['words'][] = $word;
}
?>
```